# Include functions

Tags: php, mysql

**EDIT**
Due to the overwhelming amount of advice I have received, I have fixed my problem. (After realizing the horrible php code I had written.) :D

Thanks to all!

Is there a reason that a function that is inside an included php file won't work on the parent page? I have two functions inside a php file that is included at the top of the page. However, when I try to call the function, it doesn't do anything. Here's the basic layout:

Main page:

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
<?php getPosts();?>
<div>Some HTML Code</div>
<?php endPosts(); ?>
```

Header.php

```
function getPosts() {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts order by id desc") or die(mysql_error());  
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
};
function endPosts() {
} /*End while statement */
};
```

Any idea why this won't work? I'm getting a blank white screen right now.

Comment: Are you connecting to a database? All I can tell is that you are querying a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is *so* not valid.  Why are you declaring a function inside of another function?  And there aren't supposed to be semicolons on the end of function declarations/loops.  The first thing to do is to enable error reporting.

Comment: How can error reporting be enabled? A link and a one sentence summary could be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that kind of stripping in functions will work. Aren't you getting errors from the PHP parser?

You should use something like this:

```
<?php $res = getPosts() ?>
<?php while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($res)): ?>
  <div>Some HTML code</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

With your `getPosts()` function like:

```
function getPosts()
{
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts order by id desc");

  if (!$query) die('MySQL error');

  return $query;
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, I see what he's trying to do now. +1 for figuring it out :)

Comment: I'm guessing that's the point of the functions.. at least that approach made sense to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the core understanding of what a function is. Variables inside one function cannot be accessed by another function unless passed into the function.

Also you can not start a procedural statement (while loop) in one function and end it within another function.

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially trying to create a parameterless function named `endPosts` for each row in posts. I don't even know what you're trying but this won't work. You can't declare a function twice.

And even if you could, `endPosts` doesn't do anything, so even if this would be valid code, it wouldn't output anything (except for the div).

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how PHP works. After including the header file, PHP will see something like this:

```
<?php
function getPosts() {
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts order by id desc") or die(mysql_error());  
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     };

     function endPosts() {

     } /*This is just an empty function */

}; /*And here is where getPosts ends*/
?>
```

You seem to be confused between what includes and function calls achieve.

What I think you want to be doing is something like:

```
<?php
getPosts();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?><div>Some HTML Code</div><?php
}
?>
```